# Sam and Jane play with indicators.

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

There are $30$ red balls and $50$ white balls. Sam and Jane take turns drawing balls until they have drawn them all. Sam goes first. Let $N$ be the number of times Jane draws the same color ball as Sam. Find $E[N].$

I have been proceeding with indicators...

$$  I_{j} =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if the $i^{th}$ pick is the same as the $(i-1)^{th}$ pick.} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

But I am having problems with this. Because when I proceed, I am find all the instances where the same ball is drawn on every draw, not just Jane's. I know the answer is $\frac{9}{19}$ but I can't get there. How do I change the indicators, or the probability?

Comment: ellaborate what you mean by "when I proceed, I am find all the instances where the same ball is drawn on every draw, not just Jane's."

Comment: Anyway 9/19 seems way wrong -- does it make sense that they only match _less than once_ on average over 40 draws??

Comment: I can't imagine it being less than one.  If I'm not mistaken, it should be $\approx 21$.  Does that match your simulation @MichaelChirico?  If so I'll feel more confident in my answer and post it.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes.

Comment: @JMoravitz in fact by pigeonhole they have to match at least ?10? times.

Comment: $\frac{9}{19}$ seemed wrong to me too, but it's in the solutions to the book. I am getting an answer close to 21, so I want to stick with the given solution being false. Should I delete the question?

Comment: I wouldn't bother deleting the question.  It is still a potentially useful question for future users and shows that you try to ask good questions.  Just check that the exercise number and section match between the problem and the solution.  It is also always possible that an error was made in writing the solutions (perhaps a different question was originally meant to be asked and the question got changed but the solution key didn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you started, let $I_n=\begin{cases}1&\text{if Jane draws the same color on turn}~2n~\text{as Sam did on turn}~2n-1\\
0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

We have $E[N]=E[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{40}I_n]$ which by linearity of expectation is $=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{40}E[I_n]$ and by symmetry is $40E[I_1]$

Why is $E[I_1]=E[I_2]=\dots$? Imagine that they pull out two balls and announce that they are starting in the middle of the count and that these were in fact the $(2n-1)^{st}$ and $(2n)^{th}$ balls respectively and then continue to the beginning of the count afterwards.  Clearly, the probabilities are the same regardless what label they give the turn numbers.

Let $S_r,S_w,J_r,J_w$ represent the events that Sam or Jane pulled a red or white ball on turn $2n-1$ or $2n$ respectively.

The probability that they matched color is then $Pr((S_r\cap J_r)\cup(S_w\cap J_w))=Pr(S_r)Pr(J_r|S_r)+Pr(S_w)Pr(J_w|S_w)=\frac{30\cdot 29+50\cdot 49}{80\cdot 79}$

The expected number of matches then will be $40$ times this number for a final total of:

$$\frac{1660}{79}\approx 21.01267$$

Comment: I have gotten this solution so many times, thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

## Hint:

Here's the simulated distribution (300,000 repetitions)

[image]

(let me know if you want the code, it's pretty straightforward though)